# What are some of the metaphors used by Nietzsche to refer to the end of religion?

Tags: nietzsche

What are some of the metaphors used by Nietzsche to refer to the end of religion? The end or death of religion is a recurring theme throughout Nietzsche's work. What are some of the metaphors he used to refer to it?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "metaphors". Like "twilight of the gods" and "God is dead"? Or something more extended, as in The Gay Science:"*Whither is God?" he cried; "I will tell you. We have killed him -- you and I. All of us are his murderers. But how did we do this? How could we drink up the sea? Who gave us the sponge to wipe away the entire horizon? What were we doing when we unchained this earth from its sun?*"

Comment: Hi safely, welcome to Phi.SE. As Conifold suggests, please note that your question isn't very clear. You may receive proper answers if you try to better phrase your question. Also note that in 3 lines you repeat the same line twice. Just a short advice, we don't need a long question just for the sake of its length.